# List all installed CLion plugins from the command-line?

Tags: plugins, manifest, clion, clion-plugins

I'm using CLion, and I want to obtain a list of all of the plugins I have (voluntarily) installed on it - as a text file (or printed to a terminal etc.). Can I do that...

1. From a command-line, when CLion is not running.
2. From within CLion itself?

Comment: On OS X you can list all custom plugins by `ls ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/CLion<version>/plugins`. Each plugin is installed in separate directory.